# Populate one column with data from a list and match other column data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel 2013 Workbook that has a worksheet (sheet 1) that contains two columns (one column for number and the second column for description, they are separate columns, but 1:1).

On the other worksheet, when a user enters a number from the drop-down list (pulling from the number column in sheet 1), I would like the description column next to it to auto-populate based on the data in the description column from sheet 1, and vice-versa.

Does this require VBA? If so, how can I start doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a VLOOKUP function in the description column.  I would convert both sheets to Tables (Insert ribbon) to automate copying down the formula as new rows are added.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "form" function for those cells?  You may have to customize your ribbon to add the "form" function.